# Visual Leak Detector is turned off

Tags: memory-leaks

I am using the vld 2.5 to find memory leaks and adding the additional included directories and additional library directories.

```
 #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
    #include "vld.h"
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    //VLDEnable();
    //VLDReportLeaks();
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
    }
```

here is [how to use VLD](https://vld.codeplex.com/).After I start debugging the simple program, the console tells me that the Visual Leak Detector is turned off.Then I enable VLD, but it still doesn't work.

```
VLDEnable();
VLDReportLeaks();
```

the vld.ini says:

```
     ;;  Visual Leak Detector - Initialization/Configuration File
;;  Copyright (c) 2005-2016 VLD Team
;;
;;  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
;;  modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
;;  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
;;  version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
;;
;;  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
;;  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
;;  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
;;  Lesser General Public License for more details.
;;
;;  You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
;;  License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
;;  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
;;
;;  See COPYING.txt for the full terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License.
;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Any options left blank or not present will revert to their default values.
[Options]

; The main on/off switch. If off, Visual Leak Detector will be completely
; disabled. It will do nothing but print a message to the debugger indicating
; that it has been turned off.
;
;  Valid Values: on, off
;  Default: on
;
VLD = on
; If yes, duplicate leaks (those that are identical) are not shown individually.
; Only the first such leak is shown, along with a number indicating the total
; number of duplicate leaks.
;
;   Valid Values: yes, no
;   Default: no
;
AggregateDuplicates = no
; Lists any additional modules to be included in memory leak detection. This can
; be useful for checking for memory leaks in debug builds of 3rd party modules
; which can not be easily rebuilt with '#include "vld.h"'. This option should be
; used only if absolutely necessary and only if you really know what you are
; doing.
;
;   CAUTION: Avoid listing any modules that link with the release CRT libraries.
;     Only modules that link with the debug CRT libraries should be listed here.
;     Doing otherwise might result in false memory leak reports or even crashes.
;
;   Valid Values: Any list containing module names (i.e. names of EXEs or DLLs)
;   Default: None.
;
ForceIncludeModules = 
; Maximum number of data bytes to display for each leaked block. If zero, then
; the data dump is completely suppressed and only call stacks are shown.
; Limiting this to a low number can be useful if any of the leaked blocks are
; very large and cause unnecessary clutter in the memory leak report.
;
;   Value Values: 0 - 4294967295
;   Default: 256
;
MaxDataDump = 
; Maximum number of call stack frames to trace back during leak detection.
; Limiting this to a low number can reduce the CPU utilization overhead imposed
; by memory leak detection, especially when using the slower "safe" stack
; walking method (see StackWalkMethod below).
;
;   Valid Values: 1 - 4294967295
;   Default: 64
;
MaxTraceFrames = 
; Sets the type of encoding to use for the generated memory leak report. This
; option is really only useful in conjuction with sending the report to a file.
; Sending a Unicode encoded report to the debugger is not useful because the
; debugger cannot display Unicode characters. Using Unicode encoding might be
; useful if the data contained in leaked blocks is likely to consist of Unicode
; text.
;
;   Valid Values: ascii, unicode
;   Default: ascii
;
ReportEncoding = ascii
; Sets the report file destination, if reporting to file is enabled. A relative
; path may be specified and is considered relative to the process' working
; directory.
;
;   Valid Values: Any valid path and filename.
;   Default: .\memory_leak_report.txt
;
ReportFile = 
; Sets the report destination to either a file, the debugger, or both. If
; reporting to file is enabled, the report is sent to the file specified by the
; ReportFile option.
;
;   Valid Values: debugger, file, both
;   Default: debugger
;
ReportTo = debugger
; Turns on or off a self-test mode which is used to verify that VLD is able to
; detect memory leaks in itself. Intended to be used for debugging VLD itself,
; not for debugging other programs.
;
;   Valid Values: on, off
;   Default: off
;
SelfTest = off
; Selects the method to be used for walking the stack to obtain stack traces for
; allocated memory blocks. The "fast" method may not always be able to
; successfully trace completely through all call stacks. In such cases, the
; "safe" method may prove to more reliably obtain the full stack trace. The
; disadvantage is that the "safe" method is significantly slower than the "fast"
; method and will probably result in very noticeable performance degradation of
; the program being debugged.
;
;   Valid Values: fast, safe
;   Default: fast
; 
StackWalkMethod = fast
; Determines whether memory leak detection should be initially enabled for all
; threads, or whether it should be initially disabled for all threads. If set
; to "yes", then any threads requiring memory leak detection to be enabled will
; need to call VLDEnable at some point to enable leak detection for those
; threads.
;
;   Valid Values: yes, no
;   Default: no
;
StartDisabled = no
; Determines whether or not all frames, including frames internal to the heap,
; are traced. There will always be a number of frames internal to Visual Leak
; Detector and C/C++ or Win32 heap APIs that aren't generally useful for
; determining the cause of a leak. Normally these frames are skipped during the
; stack trace, which somewhat reduces the time spent tracing and amount of data
; collected and stored in memory. Including all frames in the stack trace, all
; the way down into VLD's own code can, however, be useful for debugging VLD
; itself.
;
;   Valid Values: yes, no
;   Default: no
;
TraceInternalFrames = no
; Determines whether or not report memory leaks when missing HeapFree calls.
;
;   Valid Values: yes, no
;   Default: no
;
SkipHeapFreeLeaks = no
; Determines whether or not report memory leaks generated from crt startup code.
; These are not actual memory leaks as they are freed by crt after the VLD object
; has been destroyed.
;
;   Valid Values: yes, no
;   Default: yes
;
SkipCrtStartupLeaks = yes
```

Can someone help me？

Comment: What does vld.ini in VLD's install directory say?

Comment: @MarianSpanik Here I added in  my new post. Thank you.

Comment: I was interested in settings VLD = on and StartDisabled = no but they are OK, so I have no idea how to fix your problem :-(

Comment: @MarianSpanik ok,thank you all the same.

Comment: Don't forget to restart IDE after changing Sys.Var values

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: suddenly I realized VLD printed "Visual Leak Detector is turned off" in the Debug log. I checked everything: #include "vld.h" used, the "vld.ini" untouched, the DLL was in the PATH, so it should work.

In my case I found the solution by downloading the VLD-sources and debugging it in some test case and voilà: I had set an environment variable "VLD64" to some directory name some months ago. After deleting it everything worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

$(VLD) is internally used by VLD lib, to check "on"/"off".

```
if (!GetEnvironmentVariable(L"VLD", buffer, buffersize)) {
    GetPrivateProfileString(L"Options", L"VLD", L"on", buffer, buffersize, inipath);
}
```

Change your sys.enviroment paths variable name to VLD_PATH

$(VLD_PATH)\include
$(VLD_PATH)\lib\Win32